# Detect position of queued tasks in thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, blockingqueue

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a fixed core pool size and a `LinkedBlockingQueue` for thread pool tasks that have to wait if the entire core is busy.

Assuming that all core threads are currently busy and there are further tasks enqueued into the queue that are waiting for their future execution.

I'd like to detect the queue position of a specific task which is currently waiting. It's possible to access all queue items via `ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue().toArray()` but the items are all instances of `FutureTask`. I cannot access the contained `Callable` member which would provide enough information for an identification of my concrete task which I'm looking for.

Is there an existing mechanism or approach to detect the position of a wanted task which is currently queued?

Comment: I don't know about any existing mechanism, but there's an approach that's simple enough:  Count them.  Label each task with a serial number from counter A when you submit it, and have each task increment counter B as soon as it starts to run.  Trivial math will tell you how many tasks are in the queue and, the position of a task with label N.

Comment: That's genius! Thanks @jameslarge ! Please add this hint as answer. In the end, if there's no official solution for my requirement then I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any existing mechanism, but there's an approach that's simple enough: Count them.

Label each task with a serial number from counter A when you submit it, and have each task increment counter B as soon as it starts to run. Trivial math will tell you how many tasks are in the queue and, the position of a task with label N